# how to use spark to analyze pv,uv,ip every 5 mins

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, real-time, bigdata

How to analyze uv, pv, ip a day every 5 mins, and stored Mysql. Data is from Kafka in the following format:

```
Message sent: {"cookie":"a95f22eabc4fd4b580c011a3161a9d9d","ip":"125.119.144.252","event_time":"2017-08-07 10:50:16"}
Message sent: {"cookie":"6b67c8c700427dee7552f81f3228c927","ip":"202.109.201.181","event_time":"2017-08-07 10:50:26"}
```

It's just like 00:00-00:05 00:05--00:10 and so on ,
I used:

```
val write=new JDBCSink()
       val query=counts.writeStream.foreach(write).outputMode("complete")
          .trigger(ProcessingTime("5 minutes"))    
          .start()
```

but when I commit it on 00:01 or it's breakdown, how can I sure it not will analyse like 00:01-00:06 and so.

Answer (score 0):

Using `window` function：

```
query = counts.groupBy(window('event_time', '5 second')).agg()
query.writeStream.start()
```

Comment: pv,uv  calculate is last a day ,and window is not stateful ,if i use window like this  window($"unix_timestamp", "1 day", "5 minutes")       it also should run program at 00:00 and not 00:01